# Generate all odd integers from $i=1$ using $4i+1$, $(2i-1)/3$, and $(4i-1)/3$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, integer-sequences

I'm exploring a mathematical process that involves three operations (D, V, W) applied to odd integers, starting from $1$. Here's how these operations are defined:

- D: $ i' = 4i + 1 $
- V: $ i' = \frac{2i - 1}{3} $ (only valid if $i' $ is an odd integer)
- W: $ i' = \frac{4i - 1}{3} $ (only valid if $ i' $ is an odd integer)

The operation D is always valid. Sometimes, either D or V, or D or W may be applicable. One of these operations is randomly selected among the valid ones for each iteration. There are no limits on the number of iterations or the number of attempts, starting anew from $1$ each time.

For example, the odd number $1218886684813$ can be reached from $1$ using the sequence of choices DDDDVDDWWDWVDDDWDDWDDDDDVDDVD.

My question is: Can every odd integer be reached using this procedure, given no constraints on the number of iterations or trials?

Comment: Are fractions allowed? I mean for ex. Can I go from 1 to  $(2\times 1 -1)/3 = \frac{1}{3}$ ?

Comment: no. only odd integers.

Comment: This looks a lot like you are trying to prove the Collatz Conjecture. Is that it?

Comment: @ShubhavJain not really. For Collatz function we have $13 \mapsto 40 \mapsto 20 \mapsto 10 \mapsto 5$ and here we can convert $5$ into $21$ and $3$ only.

Comment: I checked for all odd integers 1553871. It does seem to work. However, no clear pattern has emerged.

Comment: If we write $i=2t+1$, $i'=2t'+1$, then it seems to me that exactly one of the inverse operations is available for each choice of $t'$. Namely
$$D^{-1}(4k+2)=k$$ if $t'=4k+2\equiv2\pmod4$,
$$W^{-1}(4k)=3k+1$$ if $t'=4k\equiv0\pmod4$,
$$V^{-1}(2k+1)=3k+2$$ if $t'=2k+1$ is odd.

Comment: (cont'd) So unless I made a mistake, the reverse direction is fully deterministic, and we are left with a Collatz-like game of deciding whether any initial choice $n$ leads back to zero given the rules $n\mapsto (n-2)/4$ if $n\equiv2\pmod4$; $n\mapsto (3n/4)+1$, if $n\equiv0\pmod4$ and $n\mapsto 3(n-1)/2+2$, if $n$ is odd.

Comment: I can't say whether this deterministic reformulation is easier, at par, or more difficult than Collatz :-(

Comment: I appreciate the insights shared. To clarify, the "reverse direction" from an odd integer back to 1 using the inverse operations of D, V, W is indeed a sequence where:
D inverse : $ i' = \frac{i - 1}{4} $ (only valid if $ i' $ is an odd integer)
V inverse : $ i' = \frac{3i + 1}{2} $
W inverse : $ i' = \frac{3i + 1}{4} $ (only valid if $ i' $ is an odd integer)
These operations ensure that only odd integers are generated in the sequence leading back to 1.

Comment: It's interesting to note that while these odd integers are common to the Collatz sequence, there are additional ones that are not part of the traditional Collatz progression.

For example, consider the Collatz sequence for 61: $61, 184, 92, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1$.

Now, if we apply the STI operations in reverse starting from 61 using the sequence DVDDVVVD, we obtain the odd sequence: $1, 5, 3, 13, 53, 35, 23, 15, 61$.
Notably, 13 and 3 appear in the STI sequence but are not present in the traditional Collatz sequence.

Comment: These sequences are like navigating a vast archipelago. Sailboats are the sole transport, subject to complex winds and currents. Still, a skilled navigator can reach any island, even if it means sailing in counterintuitive directions at times. This navigation, replete with detours, is akin to the D, V, and W operations used to reach a numerical goal. What appears to be a diversion is often a strategic maneuver to ensure the correct final approach.

Comment: The case of the number "27" exemplifies this concept well. The island, representing "27," seems close to the harbor, symbolizing "1." Yet, to reach it, a long and intricate journey through the archipelago is necessary: DVDDVVVDWDWWWDVVVVDVVVVVWVWVVVDWVVVWVVWVWWVVVVWV. This route, filled with unexpected turns and reversals, reflects the sophisticated path one must navigate to arrive at this seemingly nearby numerical destination.